# Understanding Efficiency in stateless drool session

Tags: drools

In stateless drool session what is more optimal to call execute method on one object or to call execute method on a list of objects?
Is there any performance gain in any approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have the overhead of n calls as compared to 1 call to `execute`. There may be further advantages in retrieving the results, but this depends on your setup.

You may have to write your rules differently; assuming that there is just one "target" object may make it easier -- again, it depends.

Why don't you benchmark it?